# Building protected routes with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, react-router

I'm trying to build a way to add protected routes to my react app. I have a Node back end with a route called `/isLoggedIn` that will respond whether the user is logged in or not. Everything works on the back end but I keep getting multiple errors in the front end. I tried to do it multiple ways but none seemed to work. This way made the most sense to me but it still doesn't really work. I do have a few additional questions.

So my app is structured like this

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Nav />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
                        <Route path="/secret" component={PrivateRoute(Secret)}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
export default function PrivateRoute(ProtectedComponent) {
    return class extends React.Component {
        state = {
            authenticated: false
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8000/isloggedin', {withCredentials: true})
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    console.log("Status ok");
                    this.setState({authenticated: true});
                } else {
                    console.log(res.error);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                this.setState({authenticated: false})
            });
        }
        render() {
            if (this.state.authenticated) {
                return <ProtectedComponent {...this.props} />
            }
            return <Redirect to="/login" />
        }
    }
}
```

So once I login and try to access the protected route, I do get a "Status ok" in my console, so everything works till that point, but then I get this error.

`Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.`

First off, I don't quite understand what this means by saying it's an unmounted component. How is this component not mounted? Isn't it being called by `<Route path="/secret" component={PrivateRoute(Secret)}/>`? Also, do I have to hit the `/isLoggedIn` route every time the user tries to access a protected page? In a lot of tutorials I see, they just set the state to something like `{loggedIn: true}` as soon as they logged in and that's all they do. Isn't this a security risk since state is just a javascript object, can't the state simply be set to true from the clients side? This whole client sided verification just seems very unsafe or maybe I just don't know a good way to build protected routes.

Lastly, if there's a better way to handle protected routes please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way of handling Public and protected routes. Here is an example to understand how to define each route either public route or protected route using React-Router-dom.

> It's just a simple way for handling routes, I hope it benefits you.

[image: s]